# Intuition for momentum operator in position space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, fourier-transform, observables

The derivation of the momentum operator in position space. But, several assumptions are usually made that a) we are dealing with the particle in free space or b) that the two representations are fourier transforms of each other.

Is there any way to understand it intuitively given how position and momentum are defined classically?

Comment: Your question is open to the point of Zen. What, specifically, is it?

Comment: There is a way to derive the momentum operator acting on some position state $|x\rangle$. Let $\hat{p}$ be some operator in position space. Suppose now that we an infinitesimal number $\epsilon$. Then, $\hat{p}(\epsilon)|x\rangle = \frac{|x+\epsilon\rangle - |x\rangle}{-i\epsilon}\rightarrow i\frac{d}{dx}|x\rangle$ where to find our answer we took the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. You can use a similar argument to find the position operator acting on a momentum state in momentum space.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure where your idea that we must deal with a free particle to derive the momentum operator in position space comes from, since that is not the case. The formula for the operators can be obtained through canonical quantization by defining the commutation relations between the position and momentum operators. By setting the commutator to be equal to $i\hbar$, we can let $\hat{x}$ = $x$ and $\hat{p}$ = $-i\hbar\partial_{x}$